# java.io.NotSerializableException: -> No constructor for deserialization found for class java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, corda

The `Collateral` state class with the member variable of type `java.sql.Timestamp` throwing below exception on deserialization in version `3.1-corda` :

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState -> data(net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState) -> No constructor for deserialization found for class java.sql.Timestamp. -> class java.sql.Timestamp -> class com.syne.cordapp.state.Collateral
```

The `java.sql.Timestamp` class already part of whitelist implemented as:

```
class CordaSerializationWhitelist : SerializationWhitelist {
    override val whitelist: List<Class<*>>
        get() = listOf(Timestamp::class.java, HashSet::class.java, Set::class.java)
}
```

And this class also added to file - `META-INF/services/net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationWhitelist`

So what could be the cause?

Comment: You can whitelist `Timestamp` all you want, still doesn't mean it has a valid constructor that Corda knows how to use.

Comment: `Timestamp` isn't listed as a supported type: https://docs.corda.net/serialization.html#jdk-types. Use `java.time.Instant`

Comment: Thank, Andreas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Andreas, if a Java class has several constructors, the Corda serialisation framework requires it to designate which constructor to use using the `@ConstructorForDeserialization` annotation.

`java.sql.Timestamp` does not do this. To use it as a field within a state, you would have to provide a custom serialiser: https://docs.corda.net/cordapp-custom-serializers.html. However, we recommend using the supported types where possible.

Comment: Yeah, I was writing the custom pluggable serializer for Timestamp, but again I had the same question in mind, whether its recommended do so for this core Java type.  Thanks, Joel.